# How to make 4 div (images inside them) to be next to each other but on small screen to wrap down

Tags: html, css

I am trying to use 4 div's inside in one master div to display 4 images next to each other, with "float:left;" it works but on smaller screen i am getting scrollbar, instead of that i want the images (div's) wrapped in new line on smaller screen...

Here is an example of my main code for that

```
<div class="first">
  <div class="sec">
    img 1
  </div>
  <div class="sec">
    img 2
  </div>
  <div class="sec">
    img 3
  </div>
  <div class="sec">
    img 4
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.first {
width: 900px;
overflow: hidden;
}
.sec {
float:left;
width:200px;
display:block;
}
```

what i am missing here ? (or doing wrong)

Comment: Is your screen smaller then `.first{ width: 900px; ` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `max-width` instead of `width` for the `.first`-class.

```
.first {
    max-width: 900px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

`width` sets a fixed width and doesn't allow the element to be neither wider or smaller. So if the screen is 500px, the element will still be 900px (and you get scrollbars).

`max-width` on the other hand, allows the element to be smaller, but not wider.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [bootstrap](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/).

> Bootstrap is the most popular HTML, CSS, and JavaScript framework for developing responsive, mobile-first web sites.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="col-md-12">
  <div class="col-md-3">
    img 1
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    img 2
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    img 3
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    img 4
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

How about a media-query?

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {
    .first {
        width: 100%;
    }
    .sec {
        float: none;
        width:100%;
    }
}
```